# golang create pdf with cyrillic

Tags: pdf, go, cyrillic

I need to create pdf file in go with cyrillic symbols. I've started with https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf but it needs 1251 symbols to produce correct cyrillic. 
I've tried

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    pwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    pdf.AddFont("Helvetica", "", pwd + "/font/helvetica_1251.json")
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetFont("Helvetica", "", 16)
    tr := pdf.UnicodeTranslatorFromDescriptor("cp1251")
    pdf.Cell(15, 50, tr("русский текст"))
    pdf.OutputFileAndClose("test.pdf")
}
```

but it produce only dots instead of text.

Then I've tried to use https://github.com/golang/freetype to create image with text and then insert it to pdf. So I've tried

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf"
    "github.com/golang/freetype"
    "image"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "image/jpeg"
    "io/ioutil"
    "image/draw"
)

func main() {
    pwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    dataFont, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pwd + "/font/luxisr.ttf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v",err)
    }
    f, err := freetype.ParseFont(dataFont)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v",err)
    }
    dst := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 800, 600))
    draw.Draw(dst, dst.Bounds(), image.White, image.ZP, draw.Src)
    c := freetype.NewContext()
    c.SetDst(dst)
    c.SetClip(dst.Bounds())
    c.SetSrc(image.Black)
    c.SetFont(f)
    c.DrawString("русский текст", freetype.Pt(0, 16))
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    pdf.AddPage()
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err = jpeg.Encode(buf, dst, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v",err)
    }

    reader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
    textName := "text1"
    pdf.RegisterImageReader(textName, "jpg", reader)
    pdf.Image(textName, 15, 15, 0, 0, false, "jpg", 0, "")
    pdf.OutputFileAndClose("test.pdf")
}
```

but as a result I receive squares instead of text because it seems that freetype needs unicode symbols for text.

Is it possible to convert strings which are generally in utf-8 to unicode? How can I create pdf or image with cyrillic text?

Thank you.

Comment: UTF-8 is unicode. Specifically it's an 8-bit lossless encoding of Unicode. So that's not your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are ignoring an error in the final line. `pdf.OutputFileAndClose` returns an error, so you should check it:

```
err := pdf.OutputFileAndClose("test.pdf")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Other than that, your first example works for me. The generated output looks like this:

[image: PDF Output]

Here is the code I used, you'll see it's very similar to yours:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf"
)

func main() {
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    pdf.AddFont("Helvetica", "", "helvetica_1251.json")
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetFont("Helvetica", "", 16)
    tr := pdf.UnicodeTranslatorFromDescriptor("cp1251")
    pdf.Cell(15, 50, tr("русский текст"))
    err := pdf.OutputFileAndClose("test.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

With the above code, the important thing is to make sure `helvetica_1251.z`, `helvetica_1251.json` and `cp1251.map` (from `$GOPATH/src/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/font`, or generated by the `makefont` tool) are all in the current directory. If you can confirm that this works for you, you can proceed to move them into the fonts directory and changing the code accordingly. My best guess is that you may be silently ignoring an error warning you about one of these files.

PS I'm running Mac OS X. If you are on another system, make sure you have a version of Helvetica with cyrillic character support installed.

**Update**

For others facing this problem in the future, I wanted to add the final solution here. From the comments below:

> Thanks to jung-kurt I found solution. You can avoid this bug on Windows by adding pdf.SetCompression(true) – Timur Shahmuratov

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm on Windows 10 and using fonts from https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/tree/master/font which I've copied to project directory. json map also comes from there. I receive no error on pdf.OutputFileAndClose. Could it be that fonts are located in separate folder "font"?

Comment: @TimurShahmuratov Hmm, then I don't know. Could it be that you need to have the font installed on your system? I'm not sure whether the PDF is generated incorrectly, or whether your system is only unable to display it correctly. You probably don't have Helvetica on Windows 10. Another thing you could try is to use the makefont tool on a font you know supports Cyrillic text, and then running the code with those generated files. Other than that, I'm out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: Tested code on Mac OSX. Yes it works with the same fonts which used in Windows. Generated pdf files differs. Reported an issue https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/issues/64